# Why isn't my signup form working until all of the form fields are filled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A few days ago, my signup form for an app I'm building was working fine. The 'create my account' button would work even if no form fields were filled, and an error message would be displayed right away. Now, when I try to submit the form, the form only will submit or show error messages when all of the fields have been filled. If I try to submit the form without filling all of the fields, nothing happens. The signup button doesn't work correctly.

The only significant change that I made that I can think of is switching the stripe plan I was using to a free trial plan instead of a plan where the purchaser of the application pays up-front. I have no idea what could be causing this problem, so I don't know what code I should post. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

The signup form I have in rails is as follows(minus some javascript that I'm using for Stripe):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset4">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.label :morning_meds, "Do you take medications in the morning?" %>
        <%= f.select :morning_meds, [['Yes'], ['No']] %>

        <%= f.label :lunch_meds, "Do you take medications at lunch?" %>
        <%= f.select :lunch_meds, [['Yes'], ['No']] %>

        <%= f.label :night_meds, "Do you take medications in the evening?" %>
        <%= f.select :night_meds, [['Yes'], ['No']] %>

        <%= f.label :time_zone, "Choose your time zone" %>
        <%= f.select :time_zone, [['Eastern'], ['Central'], ['Mountain'], ['Pacific']] %>

        <%= f.label :phone_number, "Your cell phone number" %>
        <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>

        <div class="form-row">
                    <label>Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>CVC</label>
                    <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>Expiration Date</label>
                    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, class: 'card-expiry-month' } %>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, class: 'card-expiry-year' } %>
                </div>

    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>





   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="span6 offset4"> 
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="QqrFVykfeY1+9jImvp8VjTzrQxq8VlBF+vC6V85klw0=" /></div> 



            <label for="user_name">Name</label> 
            <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text" /> 

            <label for="user_email">Email</label> 
            <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" /> 

            <label for="user_password">Password</label> 
            <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /> 

            <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label> 
            <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" /> 

            <label for="user_morning_meds">Do you take medications in the morning?</label> 
            <select id="user_morning_meds" name="user[morning_meds]"><option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
    <option value="No">No</option></select> 

            <label for="user_lunch_meds">Do you take medications at lunch?</label> 
            <select id="user_lunch_meds" name="user[lunch_meds]"><option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
<option value="No">No</option></select> 

            <label for="user_night_meds">Do you take medications in the evening?</label> 
            <select id="user_night_meds" name="user[night_meds]"><option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
<option value="No">No</option></select> 

            <label for="user_time_zone">Choose your time zone</label> 
            <select id="user_time_zone" name="user[time_zone]"><option value="Eastern">Eastern</option> 
<option value="Central">Central</option> 
<option value="Mountain">Mountain</option> 
<option value="Pacific">Pacific</option></select> 

            <label for="user_phone_number">Your cell phone number</label> 
            <input id="user_phone_number" name="user[phone_number]" size="30" type="text" /> 

            <div class="form-row"> 
                        <label>Card Number</label> 
                        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-row"> 
                        <label>CVC</label> 
                        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc" /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-row"> 
                        <label>Expiration Date</label> 
                        <select class="card-expiry-month" id="date_month"> 
<option value="1">1 - January</option> 
<option value="2">2 - February</option> 
<option value="3">3 - March</option> 
<option value="4">4 - April</option> 
<option value="5">5 - May</option> 
<option value="6">6 - June</option> 
<option value="7">7 - July</option> 
<option value="8">8 - August</option> 
<option value="9">9 - September</option> 
<option value="10">10 - October</option> 
<option value="11">11 - November</option> 
<option value="12">12 - December</option> 
</select> 

                        <span> / </span> 
                        <select class="card-expiry-year" id="date_year"> 
<option value="2012">2012</option> 
<option value="2013">2013</option> 
<option value="2014">2014</option> 
<option value="2015">2015</option> 
<option value="2016">2016</option> 
<option value="2017">2017</option> 
<option value="2018">2018</option> 
<option value="2019">2019</option> 
<option value="2020">2020</option> 
<option value="2021">2021</option> 
<option value="2022">2022</option> 
<option value="2023">2023</option> 
<option value="2024">2024</option> 
<option value="2025">2025</option> 
<option value="2026">2026</option> 
<option value="2027">2027</option> 
</select> 

                    </div> 

        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create my account" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to see the HTML source your view generates, but you likely have 1+ fields with the HTML5 `required` attribute that you are leaving blank.

By default, newer browsers like Chrome will not allow the form to submit until all fields flagged with the `required` attribute have a value. To stop this you can add the `novalidate` attribute to the `<form ...` tag.

```
<%= form_for(@user, { :novalidate => true }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I added the novalidate attribute to the form tag and it still doesn't work. If I post the html output would you mind taking a look at that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yup, I'm off to the gym for the next 90min, but will check back after. Hopefully someone else will get you sorted out before then.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I hope so too, but I appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: Are you going to add the HTML?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I thought that I added it last night, but let me add it again. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The html output is in the same block right under the embedded ruby file. Thanks!